# Xamarin forms Button click count

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When user click on btnOffline on Main page, it will redirect them to second page. I will record the time stamp when user click on button done (button_clicked event) on second Page. The error I am facing right now is when it navigates back to main page after button_clicked event, I click on btnOffline and btnDone again, the timestamp for lblEndDT changes. I only want to get the first click from second page but it still changes

Main Page

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
public string mainpagevalue;

int offlinecount = 0;
int onlinecount = 0;

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

}
private void btnOffline_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    offlinecount++;
    txtOfflineStatus.Text = "IN PROGRESS";

    Navigation.PushAsync(new SecondPage(this, lblEndDT, txtOfflineStatus, btnOnline, btnMH));


    if (offlinecount == 1)
    {
        string currentDT = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        lblStartDT.Text = currentDT;
      }


   }
```

Second Page

```
public partial class SecondPage : ContentPage
{
    Label MainPagelblEndDT;
    MainPage mainPage;
    ImageButton myImageBtn;
    int btndonecount = 0;
public SecondPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public SecondPage(MainPage mainP,Label lblEndDT)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //Get the lblEndDT reference here
    MainPagelblEndDT = lblEndDT;
    //Get the MainPage reference here
    mainPage = mainP;
}

public SecondPage(MainPage mainP, Label lblEndDT, ImageButton imageBtn)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //Get the lblEndDT reference here
    MainPagelblEndDT = lblEndDT;
    //Get the MainPage reference here
    mainPage = mainP;
    //Get the ImageButton reference here
    myImageBtn = imageBtn;
}

private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    btndonecount++;
    if(btndonecount == 1)
    {

       string edt = DateTime.Now.ToString();
       MainPagelblEndDT = edt;
       mainPage.mainpagevalue = MainPagelblEndDT.Text;
    }

       Navigation.PopAsync();
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried but it still changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on `btnOffline` and `btnDone` again, the `btndonecount` in `SecondPage` reset, so it still changes.

You should get the click count from `mainPage`, pass the `offlinecount` to `SecondPage`:

```
private void btnOffline_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    offlinecount++;
    txtOfflineStatus.Text = "IN PROGRESS";

    Navigation.PushAsync(new SecondPage(this, lblEndDT, txtOfflineStatus, btnOnline, btnMH,offlinecount));


    if (offlinecount == 1)
    {
        string currentDT = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        lblStartDT.Text = currentDT;
    }


}
```

In the `SecondPage`, get the `clickCount` and remove the `btndonecount++`:

```
   public SecondPage(MainPage mainP, Label lblEndDT, ImageButton imageBtn, int clickCount)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Get the lblEndDT reference here
        MainPagelblEndDT = lblEndDT;
        //Get the MainPage reference here
        mainPage = mainP;
        //Get the ImageButton reference here
        myImageBtn = imageBtn;

        btndonecount = clickCount;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (btndonecount == 1)
        {
            string edt = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            MainPagelblEndDT = edt;
            mainPage.mainpagevalue = MainPagelblEndDT.Text;
        }

        Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Hello thank you for the help. I tried this but my end date time is not appearing

Comment: Did you remove the `btndonecount++;`? Add a breakpoint at the line `MainPagelblEndDT = edt;` to see if it hits.

Comment: Oh I forgot to remove the btndonecount++ . It worked! Thank you :))

Comment: Hi sorry. I realise if i set the same count as the main page, when i navigate back and forth, my btn done in second page will not work anymore

Comment: So from main page I click btnOffline and it will navigate to second page right? There's a back button, and if I keep on navigate back and forth without clicking on btnDone yet, and when I finally click on btnDone after multiple times of navigation between main and second page, the timestamp does not show.